# How to specify a list of values for an input field by a query?

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I have defined a field

```
{{{field|state|default=new|input type=radiobutton}}}
```

pointing to the attribute state:

```
Dies ist ein Attribut des Datentyps [[Datentyp::Text]].

Die möglichen Werte für dieses Attribut sind:
* [[Erlaubt Wert::new]]
* [[Erlaubt Wert::accepted]]
* [[Erlaubt Wert::rejected]]
* [[Erlaubt Wert::postponed]]
```

How is it possible to change the field definition to a combobox where additional values can be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to:

- https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Property:Allows_value
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Defining_forms

> values dependent on=template name[field name] - Can be used for inputs
>   of type 'combobox', 'text with autocomplete', 'textarea with
>   autocomplete' and 'tokens'. Specifies that the current set of allowed
>   values for this field are all the values taken by this same field from
>   pages where "field name" is equal to the value selected for "field
>   name" in the current form. For example, if a template is called
>   "Restaurant" and it has template fields (not properties) named
>   "Country" and "City", and you want the set of cities that are used for
>   autocompletion to be only those cities in the country that the user
>   selected, then the field tag for the City field should look something
>   like: {{{field|City|input type=combobox|values dependent
>   on=Restaurant[Country]}}}.

Values dependent on lets you specify a semantic query to refine which allowed values to use.

Answer (score 1):

According to [mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemantic_Forms/Defining_forms#Combo_box_input) it is possbile to allow custom values via

```
{{{field|state|default=new|input type=combobox}}}
```

but the new values will not be saved into the attribute's definition.